# Setting permission on content DB

Tags: permissions, farm

I have set permission explicitly on a content DB for a user using SQL Management Studio, but after installing SharePoint SP1, the permissions set for users explicitly were deleted. What's the best approach of giving users permissions to do some basic operations?

What I am trying to do is to add a user as farm admin so he can execute PowerShell code, so I added him as local admin to the machine, as farm admin from Central Administration, and gave him permissions on SQL config DB and content DBs. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Add-SPShellAdmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607596.aspx) Cmdlet to grant such permissions for users on content DBs. You can remove the permissions via [Remove-SPShellAdmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607908.aspx), or list the granted users via [Get-SPShellAdmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607830.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @pholpar, but does this way add the user as farm admin as well? Did I follow the right steps?

Comment: As you wrote your goal is to enable the users to execute PowerShell scripts. If you use the Add-SPShellAdmin, you should not add the users manually to any groups / roles on the SP / SQL Servers. The Cmdlet perfomes all required steps. Please see the description of the Cmdlet. Note, that you should call it once (without the database parameter) for the config DB, and once for each content DBs (of course, using the database parameter).

Comment: I found the comment more helpful than the answer, you're awesome!